Trouble with reading a noise texture in GLSL
I'm writing a Perlin noise terrain generator with p5js, following this tutorial. The app ran poorly so I decided to rewrite it with shaders, something i've never used before. I started by generating a subdivided plane of varying resolution to work with, then created a noise image using p5js' perlin noise function and finally, created, loaded a set uniforms for my shader.


const SCALE = 50;

const NOISE_OFFSET = 0.05;
const NOISE_LO_BOUND = -300;
const NOISE_HI_BOUND = 300;

const SHIFT_SPEED = -0.01;

var TERRAIN_W;
var TERRAIN_H;
var NUM_COLS;
var NUM_ROWS;

var plane_model;
var terrain_texture;
var fly_offset = 0;

var default_shader;

p5.disableFriendlyErrors = true; // disables FES

var vertSrc = `
#ifdef GL_ES
precision mediump float;
#endif

attribute vec3 aPosition;
attribute vec2 aTexCoord;

uniform mat4 uModelViewMatrix;
uniform mat4 uProjectionMatrix;

varying vec2 vTexCoord;

uniform sampler2D uTerrain;
uniform int uNumCols;
uniform int uNumRows;
uniform float uScale;

float rand(vec2 co){
  return fract(sin(dot(co.xy ,vec2(12.9898,78.233))) * 43758.5453);
}

void main() {
    vec3 position = aPosition;

    vec2 uv = vec2(aPosition.x / float(uNumCols - 1), aPosition.y / float(uNumRows - 1));

    float height = texture2D(uTerrain, uv).r * 255.0;
    position.z += height;

    vec4 viewModelPosition = uModelViewMatrix * vec4(position, 1.0);

    gl_Position = uProjectionMatrix * viewModelPosition;
    vTexCoord = aTexCoord;
}
`;

var fragSrc = `
#ifdef GL_ES
precision mediump float;
#endif

varying vec2 vTexCoord;
varying vec4 vVertexColor;

void main() {
    gl_FragColor = vec4(vTexCoord.x, vTexCoord.y, vTexCoord.x + vTexCoord.y, 1.0);
}
`;

function preload() {
    default_shader = createShader(vertSrc, fragSrc);
}

function setup() {
    createCanvas(window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight, WEBGL);

    TERRAIN_W = width + floor(width / SCALE) * SCALE;
    TERRAIN_H = height + floor(height / SCALE) * SCALE;
    NUM_COLS = floor(TERRAIN_W / SCALE);
    NUM_ROWS = floor(TERRAIN_H / SCALE);

    plane_model = new p5.Geometry(NUM_COLS, NUM_ROWS, create_plane);

    default_shader.setUniform("uScale", SCALE);
    default_shader.setUniform("uNumCols", NUM_COLS);
    default_shader.setUniform("uNumRows", NUM_ROWS);

    terrain_texture = createImage(NUM_ROWS, NUM_COLS);
}

function create_plane() {
    let vert_map = []

    for (let y = 0; y < this.detailY; y++) {
        vert_map[y] = []
        for (let x = 0; x < this.detailX; x++) {
            this.vertices.push(createVector(x * SCALE, y * SCALE, 0));
            vert_map[y][x] = this.vertices.length - 1;

            this.uvs.push(x / (this.detailX - 1), y / (this.detailY - 1));
        }
    }

    for (let y = 0; y < this.detailY - 1; y++) {
        for (let x = 0; x < this.detailX - 1; x++) {
            let tl = vert_map[y][x];
            let tr = vert_map[y][x + 1];
            let bl = vert_map[y + 1][x];
            let br = vert_map[y + 1][x + 1];

            this.faces.push([tl, tr, bl]);
            this.faces.push([tr, br, bl]);
        }
    }
  
    this.computeNormals();
}

function draw() {
    fly_offset += SHIFT_SPEED;
    let yoff = fly_offset;

    terrain_texture.loadPixels();
    for (let y = 0; y < NUM_ROWS; y++) {
        let xoff = 0;
        for (let x = 0; x < NUM_COLS; x++) {
            terrain_texture.set(x, y, color(map(noise(xoff, yoff), 0, 1, 0, 255)));
            xoff += NOISE_OFFSET;
        }
        yoff += NOISE_OFFSET;
    }
    terrain_texture.updatePixels();
    default_shader.setUniform("uTerrain", terrain_texture);

    orbitControl();

    background(0);

    scale(0.5);
    rotateX(PI / 3);
    translate(-TERRAIN_W / 2, -TERRAIN_H / 2, 0);

    shader(default_shader);
    model(plane_model);
}
html, body {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}

canvas {
    display: block;
}
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/p5.js/1.9.4/p5.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/p5.js/1.9.4/addons/p5.sound.min.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">
    <meta charset="utf-8" />

  </head>
  <body>
    <main>
    </main>
    <script src="sketch.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>



The end result is a flat plane that shifts up and down randomly.

My best guess is that I messed up the resolution of the terrain_texture or how I read the UVs in the vertex shader.
I have messed around with this a lot and could not reach a solution.

Good question, but I suggest keeping your code all in one chunk so there's no need to piece it together to make it runnable. You should be able to attach p5 as a script and make it a stack snippet.

So, there were 2 problems. One, I didn't know you had to set the uniforms each draw call, and two, using
float height = texture2D(uTerrain, aTexCoord.xy).r * (255.0 + uNoiseFactor);

Is the right way to sample from the noise texture.
I would love to get some more insight as to why the previous code didn't work however since I don't see a logical fault with it.
vec2 uv = vec2(aPosition.x / float(uNumCols - 1), aPosition.y / float(uNumRows - 1));

